# R How to remap letters in a string

Tags: r, list, str-replace, remap

I’d be grateful for suggestions as to how to remap letters in strings in a map-specified way.

Suppose, for instance, I want to change all As to Bs, all Bs to Ds, and all Ds to Fs.  If I do it like this, it doesn’t do what I want since it applies the transformations successively:

```
"abc" %>% str_replace_all(c(a = "b", b = "d", d = "f"))
```

Here’s a way I *can* do what I want, but it feels a bit clunky.

```
f <- function (str) str_c( c(a = "b", b = "d", c = "c", d = "f") %>% .[ strsplit(str, "")[[1]] ], collapse = "" )

"abc" %>% map_chr(f)
```

Better ideas would be much appreciated.

James.

P.S.  Forgot to specify.  Sometimes I want to replace a letter with multiple letters, e.g., replace all As with the string ZZZ.

P.P.S.  Ideally, this would be able to handle vectors of strings too, e.g., c("abc", "gersgaesg", etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `chartr` in `base R`

```
chartr("abc", "bdf", "abbbce")
#[1] "bdddfe"
```

---

Or a package solution would be [`mgsub`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgsub/versions/1.7.2) which would also match and replace strings with number of characters greater than 1

```
library(mgsub)
mgsub("abbbce",  c("a", "b", "c"), c("b", "d", "f"))
#[1] "bdddfe"

mgsub("abbbce",  c("a", "b", "c"), c("ba", "ZZZ", "f"))
#[1] "baZZZZZZZZZfe"
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This would be brilliant, but I sometimes want to replace a letter with two letters, e.g., replace As with the string ZZZ.  My bad.  I should have specified that up front.

Comment: @JamesBejon then, it won't work.  I was thinking that you need only a single letter replacement.  Sometimes, we take examples literally

Comment: @JamesBejon can i ask why the `str_replace_all` is not working for you.  It is a very compact code

Comment: Yep.  It was a poorly specified question.  Apologies.  Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: @JamesBejon I understand the problem in the `str_replace` as it is recursively doing the replacement

Comment: Brilliant!  mgsub is exactly what I'm after!!  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is more elegant? It will also return warnings when values aren't found.

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
mappings <- c(a = "b", b = "d", d = "f")

str_split("abc", pattern = "") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  mapvalues(from = names(mappings), to = mappings) %>%
  str_c(collapse = "")

# The following `from` values were not present in `x`: d
# [1] "bdc"
```

Comment: That's certainly an improvement on mine.  Thanks.  Appreciate it.